# WPF databinding problem

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, grid, tabcontrol

I have a grid inside a canvas on a tab.
The grid contains a large bitmap image,
I have(tried to) bound the size of the grid to the size of the tab and also have a five pixel margin around the grid.

imageTab.cs

```
    public ImageTab(SendInfo sendInfo, int numImge, int numAccs)
    {
        imageDisplay = new ImageDisplay(sendInfo, numImge, numAccs);
        imageDisplay.ClipToBounds = true;
        CreateCanvas();
    }

    private void CreateCanvas()
    {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.Children.Add(imageDisplay);
        this.AddChild(canvas);
    }
```

ImageDisplay.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProj.ImageDisplay">

      <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=ActualHeight}">
          <Image/>
      </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The grid comes off the bottom of the tab area slightly causing the bottom of the image to be cut off.
Is there a problem with my databinding, do I need to apply some sort of offset to it? (size of tab - 10pixels for the margin?)

Comment: If you want the grid to fill the tab, then why are you putting it inside a Canvas? Canvas is for cases where you need to position controls at exact (X,Y) coordinates with exact sizes -- it's no good for dynamic layouts like "fill the parent".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the Height property at all (also realize that it is incorrect to do so as you have it when you consider the 5 pixel margin, i.e., it would be off by 10 pixels).

Just leave `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` at their default values (which is `Stretch`) to get the effect you are after here.

Try this on a new `Window` to see what I mean:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="438" Width="587" Background="Pink">
    <Grid Background="Black"  Margin="5">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The grid here will be black and will always stretch to the size of the window, using a 5 pixel margin which you will see because the Window's back color is pink.